# Access Spark's webUI from remote computer (home)?

Tags: apache-spark

I have set a Jupyter notebook server in my office and can access it from home by just going to works_pulic_ip:8888, 
Lately I've set a spark cluster at work as well, is there a way to access sparks webUI from my home?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, you need to open Spark UI ports like [spark.master.ui.port,spark.worker.ui.port and spark.ui.port](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html) for Public (External) IP

Comment: could you be more specific?

Comment: you need to enable firewall for your all ui port.